# Executing following statements when base case met

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

I am building an English ruler using recursion in java. In the drawing of ticks using drawRuler function, I faced a problem that when the value is 0, how the control will execute the following statements. My base condition is:
if(centalLength >= 1) and the recursive call lies inside this control statement. Facing problem in drawInterval(centralLength - 1). Anyone can help, I want to understand what will be done after the base case has been met.

```
public static void drawRuler(int nInches, int majorLength) { 

        drawLine(majorLength, 0);      

        for(int j = 1; j <= nInches; j++) { 
            drawInterval(majorLength - 1);     
            drawLine(majorLength, j);      
        } 
    } 

    private static void drawInterval(int centralLength) { 

        if (centralLength >= 1) {           
            drawInterval(centralLength - 1);     
            drawLine(centralLength); 
            drawInterval(centralLength - 1); 
        }
    } 

    private static void drawLine(int tickLength, int tickLabel) { 

        for (int j = 0; j < tickLength; j++)
            System.out.print("-");

        if (tickLabel >= 0)
            System.out.print(" " + tickLabel);

        System.out.print("\n");

    }

    private static void drawLine(int tickLength) { 

     drawLine(tickLength, -1);

 }
```

The code is error-free. I want to understand how the next statements will execute after the base condition met.

Comment: Base case is met when centralLength becomes equal to zero. Any recursive call to drawInterval that meets base case, ie called with a param centralLength=0 will return immediately to the invoking method.

Comment: In drawInterval() method, when if(0 >= 1) condtion will become false, how the drawLine(centralLength - 1) will execute???

Comment: It does not. If you call drawLine with centralLength=0, the recursive calls stop and returns. Calling drawInterval with centralLength=1 would invoke drawInterval(0), which returns immediately, it then calls drawLine(0) which prints something out and returns, and then calls drawInterval(0) again, which returns immediately.

Comment: @Martin'sRun  you said about the  drawInterval(0), which returns immediately, my question is that when this statement executes drawInterval(centralLength - 1); ? and  if you put 0 in it and  if (0 >= 1) the if condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

When either `drawInterval(majorLength - 1)` or `drawInterval(centralLength - 1);` is called with 0, the draw interval calls will be skipped, drawing lines at `drawLine(majorLength, j)` for `j <= nInches` times. So your recursion is bad - there shouldn't be a loop in it anywhere, it itself is the loop.

For instance  `drawRuler(1, 99)` will draw 99 lines at 1.

Here's the steps it'll take:

It calls draw line at 0, then initializes a for loop.

The first iteration of the for loop, majorLength - 1 is zero, so draw interval is a no-op.

Then it calls draw line with 1 and 0.

Then it loops, and majorLength - 1 is still zero, so draw interval no-ops, and draw line is called with 1 and 1.

Then it loops again until j = 99, calling draw line(1,j) every time, thus drawing 99 lines.

Any issues you're encountering with it are related to your mixing of recursion and loops. You have to be extremely careful with that.

Comment: In drawInterval() method, when if(0 >= 1) condtion will become false, how the drawLine(centralLength - 1) will execute???

Comment: It won't, but of the draw line call in the for loop of draw ruler will.